# Запрос по минимальной дате postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица с данными в БД postgresql 
[image: Таблица]

Какой запрос нужно написать, что бы остались только записи с минимальными(ранними) датами?
[image: Вывод]

Comment: min(date) и first_value() over (partition by uid order by date asc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> create table "test_over"
> (
>   "uid" int,
>   "sum" int,
>   "date" date
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into "test_over" ("uid","sum","date") values 
> (1, 50,'2018-01-01'),
> (1, 30,'2018-01-05'),
> (1, 60,'2018-01-20'),
> (2,  0,'2018-01-05'),
> (2, 30,'2018-01-03'),
> (3, 80,'2018-01-15'),
> (8,100,'2018-01-22'),
> (8, 50,'2018-01-23');
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select distinct
>   "uid",
>   first_value ("sum") over (partition by "uid" order by "date" asc),
>   first_value ("date") over (partition by "uid" order by "date" asc)
> from "test_over"
> order by
>   "uid"
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> uid | first_value | first_value
> --: | ----------: | :----------
>   1 |          50 | 2018-01-01 
>   2 |          30 | 2018-01-03 
>   3 |          80 | 2018-01-15 
>   8 |         100 | 2018-01-22
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=24ab19c0310b52f98afcd0c4a50f68d7)*